# как в строке из набора цифр, заменить определенные, на те, которые я задам на python

Tags: python

Дана строка:
11211212222121

Алгоритм:

```
НАЧАЛО
ПОКА нашлось (111) ИЛИ нашлось (222)
    ЕСЛИ нашлось (111)
        ТО заменить (111 на 2)
    КОНЕЦ ЕСЛИ
    ЕСЛИ нашлось (222)
        ТО заменить (222 на 1)
    КОНЕЦ ЕСЛИ
КОНЕЦ ПОКА
КОНЕЦ
```

> (написать на Python)необходимо пройтись по этой строке и если в ней найдены 3 цифры **1** их нужно заменить на цифру **2** и если найдены 3 цифры **2** необходимо их заменить на цифру **1**

Должно получиться:

```
12
```

Comment: алгоритм есть, что мешает его закодить?

Comment: я не знаю как на python использовать поиск в строке, как найти эти единицы и двойки, когда они перемешаны в строке. Как их заменить, тоже не знаю

Comment: а как с такой логикой из `11211212222121` должно `12` получиться? `11211212222121` -> `112112112121` После чего цикл останавливается

Comment: вначале из этой строки находятся 2 раза 3 единицы и 2 раза 3 двойки и меняются на цифры 2 и 1 соответственно и строка становится: 221112, после чего снова срабатывает цикл и находятся вновь 3 единицы и 3 двойки и строка становится: 12

Comment: как-то тогда задание написано очень непонятно, т.е. 111 не должно быть подряд? хотя описанный вами алгоритм говорит обратное

Comment: извините за некорректное объяснение задачи, я новичок на данной платформе. Единицы и двойки могут быть расположены в любом порядке, но если 3 единицы или 3 двойки присутствуют в строке, то они заменяются в соответствии с условием

Comment: все равно не понимаю как это работает `11231` на что должно быть заменено? на `223` или `232`? распишите пожалуйста свой алгоритм по шагам - ну очень непонятно и неоднозначно он сейчас звучит (вернее задание, а не алгоритм).

Comment: @Zhihar, там нет троек, давайте проще. Есть строка из 7 единиц и 7 двоек: 11111112222222, в ней 6 единиц меняются на 2 двойки и 6 двоек меняются на 2 единицы, но при этом остаются одна единица и одна двойка: 1122 - те что преобразовались, 12 - те что остались. Итог 111222! И потом они так же заменяются на 1 и 2 соответственно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из комментариев @Андрей Александрович, примерно понял что именно требовалось :)

в этом случае код может выглядеть так:

```
text = '11211212222121'
old_text = ''

while old_text != text:
  old_text = text

  # подсчитать кол-во единиц и двоек
  count1 = text.count('1')
  count2 = text.count('2')

  # произвести замену
  text = '2' * (count1 // 3) + '1' * (count2 // 3) + '1' * (count1 % 3) + '2' * (count2 % 3)

print(text)
```

Comment: спасибо, все хорошо работает)

Answer (score 0):

Давай с того что 12 у тебя никак не получится в дано: 11211212222121. Попробуй сам свой алгоритм прогнать в голове.

Если брать дано: 11211212222121
то получится 112112121121

Если убрать из дано одну 2:
1121121222121
11211211121
112112221
1121111
11212

Сам код:

```
a =  1121121222121
def repl(a):
    if '111' in str(a):
        a = str(a).replace('111','2')
        repl(a)
    elif '222' in str(a):
        a = str(a).replace('222', '1')
        repl(a)
    else:
        print(a)
repl(a)
```

Вы уверены что должно получиться 12?

Comment: Да,12. Вначале из этой строки находятся 2 раза 3 единицы и 2 раза 3 двойки и меняются на цифры 2 и 1 соответственно и строка становится: 111222(единицы и двойки могут быть вперемешку),  в конце из строки 111222 должен сработать алгоритм и получиться 12

Comment: 6 единиц убирается и 6 двоек в 1 цикле, остается 12 и к ним приписываются замененные 2 двойки и 2 единицы, получается: 111222, и потом вторым циклом 3 единицы и 3 двойки меняются и получается 12

Comment: @Edward Grachev, можно просто двумя `replace` в цикле гонять пока старая и новая строки не станут одинаковыми

Comment: @Zhihar, если вы поняли меня, я буду благодарен вам если вы оптимизируете данный код, просто я не понял.